# contentsOfDirectoryAtPath returning null (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm having trouble displaying all files in directory. I did make a directory named "saves" in the same folder as all the app files.

I use this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *imageFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"saves" error: &error];

NSLog(@"FILES: %@", imageFiles);
```

Can anyone help me out, because this code logs "null" - so pretending there isn't anything in the folder, but in the folder I made one directory and two empty files.

Comment: check the error message and post it.
Add NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *documentDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Check for files in the test directory:

```
 NSArray *filePaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"] error:nil]];
```

Comment: I want to get an array of all files in that directory, so if there are 3 text files, display the names of that 3 text files.

Comment: @sjors above code will give you the path of all the files present in the test directory :)

Comment: NSString *documentDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   
    NSArray *AllFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saves"] error:nil];
    
    NSLog(@"FilesTree %@", AllFiles); returns null to me.

Comment: Do the directory saves exist in your documents directory? Have you creating it before accessing its contents?

Comment: I made the files in finder in the project folder, they are copied to my ipad aren't they?

Comment: Yes they are copied to your iPad, but not in the documents directory, they are present in the APP's Bundle

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to save a file in your main bundle. Are you doing this on the simulator or on an actual device?  You can't save files in your main bundle on a device.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *imageFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"saves" error:    &error];


Not sure what ypou expect this to do...
NSLog(@"FILES: %@", imageFiles);

try this
NSLog(@"Image file count %d", [imageFiles count]);

for ( int i - 0; i <= [imageFiles count] - 1; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"file name : %@", [imageFiles objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

code NOT tested but I think you get the idea...